# Find/Replace various lines in file with find/sed via bash

Tags: bash, sed

I use the below command to find/replace text in files of the name indicated within the path shown.

I need to use a similar command for a number of lines in a different file of which there are over 1,000 so I can't so them all individually.

```
find /var/www/html/files/ -name "file.php" -print | xargs sed -i 's/Find Text/Replace Text/g'
```

The above finds files in the location `/var/www/html/files/` (and folders within) and finds the text 'Find Text' and replaces it with 'Replace Text'.

How could I use this if I wanted to find a whole line within the php files and replace it with three new lines of code?

Alternatives I could look at are  to add the lines of code at the end of each file OR to simply copy a whole new file to each location and overwrite the previous one.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some sample input data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say this is my file :

```
$ cat change_version.py 
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import json

obj=json.load(open('input.json'))
obj['version'] = "WHATEVER"
print(json.dumps(obj, indent="  ")) . <-- I want to replace this line
```

Then this will do :

```
cat change_version.py | sed $'s/print.*/morethan\\\noneline/g'
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import json

obj=json.load(open('input.json'))
obj['version'] = "WHATEVER"
morethan
oneline
```

Let me know if it works for you.